# How to check type directly from type that passed through template function not from variable?

Tags: c++

I have the following template function defined at the header file.

```
template <class T> T* spawnEnemy(SpawnDirection dir);
```

My intention is to create a generic spawning function that accepts **type** of enemy as a template parameter and return the spawned object from the function.

The following is **incorrect** implementation but I use it to express what I want to achieve.

```
template <class T> T* ObjectSpawner::spawnEnemy(SpawnDirection dir)
{
    if(_enemiesPool->isAnyFreeObjects())
    {
        T* enemy = NULL;
        if(typeof(T*) == Zombie01)   // This line is INCORRECT
            enemy = dynamic_cast<T*>(_enemiesPool->popFreeObjectAndAddToActiveListForType(ZOMBIE));
        else if ...

        return enemy;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

That is I need to be able to do type checking from **T**, so I can appropriately call function

```
popFreeObjectAndAddToActiveListForType(int type)
```

with correct value as its input.

So how can I do type checking in situation like this within template function?

EDIT:
After got a suggestion from [stephen lin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191315/how-to-check-type-directly-from-type-that-passed-through-template-function-not-f#comment21403834_15191315) and [nvoigt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191315/how-to-check-type-directly-from-type-that-passed-through-template-function-not-f/15191385#comment21403895_15191315), then I see that this design has a flaw but it's because I top it up from what I already. The easier is to let function have another **type** parameter and not involve with template but do need to cast to specific type later. Anyway, it's good to know a solution for this situation.

Comment: `T*` is already a specific type once you instantiate the template, so I'm unclear why you need to check it. If you want `T*` to map to specific constant for the `int type` parameter, then you need some kind of type trait.

Comment: Can't your function be called with a type parameter, too? Like " template <type T> void popFreeObjectAndAddToActiveListForType()" ? Why have an int for types at all?

Comment: @haxpor what nvoight said

Comment: Firstly I came up with specific functions for each spawning type, and I need to have one generic function to cover all types to spawn. Anyway, at this stage I would like to remain functionality of popFreeObjectAndAddToActiveListForType() and its parameter as it is. At least doing this way (above) will reduce code.

Comment: @haxpor I am not sure, but I think my answer below with type traits might be what you want..I could be wrong though.

Comment: Hey thanks guys, this triggers me about the design flaw. I have edited the question at the bottom. Anyway, I'm still seeking for solution for this kind of situation. I'm reading and trying answers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want something like this (using type traits):

The following section of code must be put outside of the class section.

```
template <typename T>
struct EnemyTraits { };

template <>
struct EnemyTraits<Zombie01> { static const int pop_type = ZOMBIE; };

template <>
struct EnemyTraits<Vampire01> { static const int pop_type = VAMPIRE; };
```

The following function should be defined in header file as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

```
template <typename T> T* ObjectSpawner::spawnEnemy(SpawnDirection dir)
{
    if(_enemiesPool->isAnyFreeObjects())
    {
        const int pop_type = EnemyTraits<T>::pop_type;
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(_enemiesPool->popFreeObjectAndAddToActiveListForType(pop_type));
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got several useful tidbits about C++ and this interesting type traits.

However, I got linker error saying that "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "Zombie01* ObjectSpawner::spawnEnemy<Zombie01>(ObjectSpawner::SpawnDirection)", referenced from: ... ". I believe it's something to do with where to declare or its own syntax.

I took a look at [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/type_traits/detail/is_mem_fun_pointer_impl.hpp) and despite not exactly what we're doing here, but I can't find any mis-steps.

Comment: I defined generic template in header file, and the specialization template in the implement file as I got a compile error if I put it in header file. I also take a look at this [link](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442#boost) as well, but not work so far.

Comment: did you put all the above in the header file? [(helpful info)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)...you can do explicit instantiation too as an alternative, but that's a bit less standard

Comment: I separated it, see [here](https://gist.github.com/haxpor/5080097).
It's link error, no compile error, it cannot seem to find a reference spawnEnemy<Zombie01>() to work with.

Comment: yeah, that needs to be in the header, why does that error? is it because `Zombie01` is undefined when the template is defined?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't put it there in header file, if I put it there it shows error "Explicit specialization of `EnemyTraits` in class scope".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25490/discussion-between-stephen-lin-and-haxpor)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is using `dynamic_cast`,  if `T` is base class of `Zombie01` :

```
T *enemy = dynamic_cast<Zombie01*>(x);
if (!enemy)
{
   // x can not cast to Zombie01
   // do something else
}
```

However, it is recommend to minimizing the usage of `dynamic_cast`

Another idea is using [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

> If T and U name the same type with the same const-volatile
>   qualifications, provides the member constant value equal to true.
>   Otherwise value is false.

However, I'm trying to use Scott Meyers's hint from Effective C++:

> "Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form "if the object is
>   of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do
>   something else," slap yourself.

Comment: I try to avoid using dynamic_cast, it requires too many if else-if. Also I'm not using C++11 right now so I cannot find is_same, but thanks for introduce it to me.

Comment: @M.M. fyi, it doesn't really matter if `T` is a base class of `Zombie01` actually, dynamic_cast will [cross cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321664/checking-whether-a-cross-cast-could-possibly-work) any two polymorphic pointers.

Comment: @StephenLin: You're right. I assumed "multiple non-virtual derivation" isn't used for those objects.